# Access items inside of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a rather simple JSON file that I'm trying to access the items inside of. I had this working but for some reason it no longer works and it is making my brain hurt. Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "firstItem":
      {
        "message": "firstItem is working",
        "value": ["hello", "world"]
      }
  },
  {
    "secondItem":
      {
        "message": "secondItem is working",
        "value": ["hello", "aliens"]
      }
  }
]
```

Note that there is an array of two objects (firstItem and secondItem) which have objects within them (message and value). I am trying to access these items like so:

```
// the json from above is equal to json

json.map(items => {
  console.log(items.firstItem.message)
  console.log(items.firstItem.value.join(", "))
  console.log(items.secondItem.message)
  console.log(items.secondItem.value.join(", "))
})
```

As always, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I put the closing parenthesis on the joins. This was not part of my issue. I guess I'm too used to VSCode doing it for me. :)

Comment: `console.log(items.firstItem.value.join(", ")` and `console.log(items.secondItem.value.join(", ")` are missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: What is the expected output? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a closing parentheses on your `console.log join` statements. The second and larger problem was that with `map` you are looping through `firstItem` first and then `secondItem`, so in the first iteration `map` doesn't know what `secondItem` is. I changed the names of each object to `"item"` and halved the code inside `map` to solve the problem:

```js
const json = [
  {
    "item":
      {
        "message": "firstItem is working",
        "value": ["hello", "world"]
      }
  },
  {
    "item":
      {
        "message": "secondItem is working",
        "value": ["hello", "aliens"]
      }
  }
]

json.map(items => {
  console.log(items.item.message);
  console.log(items.item.value.join(", "));
})
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for. I think the biggest issue is my JSON formatting. I'm going to play around with things and see if I can get what I need. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that there is an array of two objects (firstItem and secondItem) which have objects within them (message and value). I am trying to access these items like so:

The example you show, shows an array containing two objects, where the first object has a property called firstItem and the second property has a property called secondItem. The properties in both the objects are objects themselves and both have two properties called message and value.

I hope that makes sense.